# Convert pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to modify my dataframe using JSON and then convert that pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD back to dataframe to write that to remote file. pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD doesn't have any write method.

e.g.

```
import json
df = spark.read.table("table")
json_data = df.rdd.map(lambda row: json.dumps({"index": {"_index": "index", "_id": 
row["id"]}}) + "\n" + json.dumps(row.asDict()))
```

Now here `json_data` is `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD`
When I tried to convert using toDF() method its giving error:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:

Basically I need to convert this modified `json_data` to dataframe so I can use write method to push that to remote file. `PipelinedRDD` doesn't support write functionality.

```py
df.write.format("filetransfer").options().save("/filepath/file.json")
```

Comment: You are attempting to write out a single JSON file and Spark doesn't do that even with `df.write.json(...)` due to Spark being a big data parallel processing framework. You also appear to be trying to combine or create two records per source record but instead you are concatenating two independent JSON objects per output line/row -- \n does not act as a separate for two elements in a RDD.